Send Mail after Form Submit to Google Sheet
I found this wonderful app script on Github for writing to my Google spreadsheet. It works perfectly. Now I'm looking for a way to send myself an email after the script has run. But this is proving difficult. I want to call my own EmailNote() function. It works very well on its own, i.e. when started from the editor, but when I try to integrate it in the doPost(e) script, no email is sent. Kindly ask for help!
My doPost(e) Script:
// Manual: https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet

var sheetName = 'Entries' var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
 
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}

My EmailNote() Script:
function EmailNote() {
  var emailSender = "my.mail@gmail.com";
  var emailRecipients = ["my.mail@gmail.com", "my@mail.com"];
  var emailSubject = "App Script - Email";
  var emailBody ='App Script - Email';

  // send mail
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailRecipients.join(","), emailSubject, emailBody, {
    from: emailSender
  });
}


Where did you call EmailNote()? I would place it in finally and if you do not want to get an email if failed, set a flag in the catch

After new row...
...
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
EmailNote();

I would move it to finally and set a global flag in the catch to not send am email if the update fails. Also wrap the email sending in try and catch to see if it gives an error message

No chance... tried everything on catch and finally position, nothing works. It seems the doPost(e) cannot trigger another function within the same script. I guess I need a workaround. Have no idea yet.

Adding another answer as this is something that is a very common pitfall new and often even experienced engineers fall prey to.

Make sure you redeploy your app after making any changes. And after deployment use the updated endpoint.


You are so right!

You are not at all calling intialSetup and EmailNote functions inside your doPost method.
const sheetName = 'Entries' 

function doPost (e) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    // Call EmailNote here

    EmailNote()

    
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
 
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}


Yes, I haven't shown it here, but I've tried calling it at different places in my script. Also the position you show. Nothing happens. DoPost(e) works, but the email isn't sent. That's why I'm now looking for a workaround. Thank you.

I am using similar code in some production apps and it is working great e.g., radheshyamdas.com
